# Python 3: Programmatically converting list of hex numbers to binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I have a list of hex numbers **as strings** and I want to convert all of them to binary. I'm using Python 3. What's a good way to do this?

**EDIT:** The numbers are in the format `'0x23051fb2'`, i.e. they start with an `0x`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Nurdok/4096182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hexlist = ['0x23051fb2', '0xAB', '0xAC']
binlist = [bin(int(x, 16)) for x in hexlist]
```

Now if we do `print(binlist)` we get:

```
['0b100011000001010001111110110010', '0b10101011', '0b10101100']
```

Comment: @RamRachum The `int()` built-in will manage just fine to convert that, since `16` is specified as the base.

Comment: Note that if the leading `0b` is undesired, then `format(int(x, 16), 'b')` can be used instead... Of course - whether @RamRachum means "bitstrings" or "integers" as "binary" probably needs to be clarified :)

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['0x1A', '0xFF', 'FF']
print map(lambda x: bin(int(x, 16)), lst)
```

Output:

```
['0b11010', '0b11111111', '0b11111111']
```

Comment: Will trailing `0x` be a problem?